# Display Names based on Weekend (Saturday and Sunday)

Tags: javascript

I have an input like this: var names = ["Ram","Shyam","Neel","Nik"];
I need to display these names in a table which will be tagged against Weekend, for Ex:
[Weekend Name Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4MjW.png)

Points:
-This table will keep generating the names for weekends month by month.
-Not one name should be same as the last weekend name
-The array can differ from size 2 to 5.

I am quite new to JS and tried below code, but this takes more manual effort:

```js
var array = ["Ram","Shyam","Neel","Nik"];

var is_weekend =  function(dt){
    if(dt.getDay() == 6 || dt.getDay() == 0)
    {
        return "weekend";
    } 
}

if(is_weekend(new Date())){
    alert("yes");
}else{
    alert("NO");

    var a = new Date();
    var days = new Array(7);
    days[0] = "Sunday";
    days[1] = "Monday";
    days[2] = "Tuesday";
    days[3] = "Wednesday";
    days[4] = "Thursday";
    days[5] = "Friday";
    days[6] = "Saturday";
    var r = days[a.getDay()];
    var rows = [{
        name: array[0],
        day: days[6],
        date: ""
    }, {
        name: array[0],
        day: days[0],
        date: ""
    }, {
        name: array[1],
        day: days[6],
        date: ""
    }, {
        name: array[0],
        day: days[0],
        date: ""
    }, {
        name: array[1],
        day: days[6],
        date: ""
    }];

    var html = "<table border='1|1'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        html+="<tr>";
        html+="<td>"+rows[i].name+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+rows[i].day+"</td>";
        //html+="<td>"+rows[i].date+"</td>";

        html+="</tr>";

    }
    html+="</table>";
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Looking for some help here.

Comment: whats the expected result for the input you given? Same as the image?

Comment: @Nitheesh, Yes and that table will generate every month with same name, and day but with updated Date.

Comment: `is_weekend(new Date())` just checks the current day.  Instead you'd need to loop over a series of dates, presumably with a specific start and end date in mind.

Comment: Could you please explain, in what logic names are associated with days ?! bcz every name having different associated value.

Comment: @nityanarayan44, Names can be associated with any date, just that no name should repeat for two continuous weekends and one name should be associated with both days of a week,i.e, Saturday and Sunday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are looping over the dates in the month from the current date to the last date in the month, we check if the date currently iterated over is a weekend date or not, if it is we add a name from the array to it and other properties and skip otherwise.

```
const is_weekend = function(dt){
        if(dt.getDay() == 6 || dt.getDay() == 0) return true;
        else false;
    }

var array = ["Ram","Shyam","Neel","Nik"];
var currArrIndex = 0;

var start = new Date(); //current date
var end = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth()+1, 0); //last date of the month
var rows = Array();
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]


var currDate = start;
console.log(currDate);
while(currDate <= end){
    //alert(currDate);   
    console.log(currDate);
    if(is_weekend(currDate)){ //if the date is a weekend date
        let dayName = days[currDate.getDay()]; //get week day of the current date
        let rowElement = {
            name : array[currArrIndex], //set one of the names from array from first to last
            day : dayName,
            date : currDate.toLocaleDateString()
        }
        rows.push(rowElement);
        if(currDate.getDay() == 0){ //change after every week
            currArrIndex ++; //current index array name is already assigned to last weekend, hence move to next array name
            currArrIndex %= array.length; //if current index goes beyond array length resign to 0
        }
    }

    var newDate = currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 1);
    currDate = new Date(newDate);
}

var html = "<table border='1|1'>";
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let htmlElement = `
    <tr>
    <td>${rows[i].name}</td>
    <td>${rows[i].day}</td>
    <td>${rows[i].date}</td>
    </tr>`;
    html+=htmlElement;

}
html+="</table>";
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: please add some explaning to your code. Pure code answers will most likely never help someone who is new to javascript, which is the case here. Thanks.

Comment: @Pankaj Prajapati, the output is not as expected.One name is expected on both Saturday and Sunday and it should only change the next weekend. For Ex, please see the image attached in the Question above.

Comment: @Sonal Fixed that part of change in name only after a week. Please check it now and let me know if it is what u expect. Thanks.

Comment: @PankajPrajapati, It works as expected, but the only line creating issue is "var end = new Date(start.getFullYear(), start.getMonth()+1, 0);", when i tried to remove this and hardcoded the date then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var names = ["Ram","Shyam","Neel","Nik"];
var weekdays = ["Saturday", "Sunday"];
var nameIndex=0;
var nameLength = names.length;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = "<table border='1|1'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {  
        for(var j = 0; j<weekdays.length; j++) {
          html+="<tr>";
          html+="<td>"+names[i]+"</td>";
          html+="<td>"+weekdays[j]+"</td>";
          //html+="<td>"+rows[i].date+"</td>";
          html+="</tr>";
        }
    }
    html+="</table>";
    document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```